# Unable to find node on an unmounted component (react-sortable-hoc)

Tags: react-native, wordpress-gutenberg

A have small gutenberg block, but i have errors.

Unable to find node on an unmounted component
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs[collection].indexOf')

Current wp version uses React 16.13.1

How can i fix this? Thanks!

```
    import {SortableContainer, SortableElement} from 'react-sortable-hoc';
    
    registerBlockType('ay/sortable', {
        title: __('Sortable'),        
        attributes: {
            items: {
                type: 'array',
                default: [
                    'Item 1',
                    'Item 2',
                    'Item 3',                    
                ],
            },
        },
    
        edit(props) {
            const {
                attributes: {items},
                setAttributes,
            } = props;
    
            const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li>{value}</li>);
    
            const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
                return (
                    <ul>
                        {items.map((value, index) => (
                            <SortableItem
                                key={`item-${value}`}
                                index={index}
                                value={value}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                );
            });
    
            const onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
                setAttributes(({items}) => ({
                    items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
                }));
            };
    
            return (
                <div>
                    <SortableList items={items} onSortEnd={onSortEnd} />
                </div>
            );
        },
    
        save(props) {
            return null;
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code provided, there are two critical imports missing for your block to work, add:

```
...
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
...
```

Also check that your `package.json` lists `react-sortable-hoc` as a dependancy:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0"
},
```

After adding the missing imports and making sure the dependancy is present/installed, your block should compile without error. I tested your code all the other parts of the `edit()` function are fine and the output was a sortable list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem was in the wrong configuration of the webpack. I tried using the method from the documentation, and I managed to make a [working solution](https://github.com/yarovikov/gutenberg-sortable-block). But you pushed me on this right path :)

Comment: @AlexYarovikov You're welcome, glad to know that you found the solution!